# Why is there a difference in size of bytes between an array and a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, sizeof

I'm going through a beginner course on C++ and like to pause the lesson and tinker around with the code on what I'm learning. I had the idea to use the sizeof() operator in C++ on a vector and an array. Ended up finding out that with the same amount of numbers in the vector and array the size of them in bytes comes of different. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()  {

   std::vector <int> test_scores { 100,99,90,70,75 };

   int test_scores_array[]{ 100,99,90,70,75 };

   std::cout << sizeof(test_scores) << std::endl;
   std::cout << sizeof(test_scores_array) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

with an output of this

```
16
20
```

after about 30 minutes of googling I can't figure out why the size is different. I don't really "need" to know but I just find it really interesting that it is different and would really like to know why.

Comment: Because `sizeof(vector)` doesn't do what you think it does. If you create a vector containing the first million prime numbers, you will be surprised to learn that its `sizeof` is still just a few bytes.

Comment: `sizeof(test_scores)` is the size of the std::vector object, and does not include the size of the allocated memory the std::vector object has a pointer to.

Comment: Even worse, `int *stillAnArray = test_scores_array` would not give you 20 for `sizeof(stillAnArray)`. for a pointer variable, sizeof reports the size of the _pointer itself_ and does not dereference or look for null terminators (no fancy ops).